# Accessing all rows from a table based on foreign key used in other table

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, so after trying a lot, I couldn't find appropriate solution
    on Stackoverflow. That's why I posted my question.[May be it's a repeating 
    question]

I have 2 tables T1 and T2.
    Structure given below:

```
Tables:
T1:
Task     Category     Estimated_Cost
 1        9100           100
 2        9100            15
 3        9100             6
 4        9200             8
 5        9200            11

T2:
Voucher    Task        Actual_Cost
  1          1            10
  2          1            20
  3          1            15
  4          2            32
  5          4             8
  6          5             3
  7          5             4
```

I want the result as:

```
Category     Estimated_Cost     Actual_Cost
 9100           121                77
 9200            19                15
```

Which query to use for this?

Comment: Half the problem with problems (particularly when you're new to something) is knowing how to describe it and knowing what to ask:  You want the **sum** of `Estimated_Cost` and `Actual_Cost`, **grouping by** `Category`.  In order to get the sum of `Actual_Cost` you need to **join** the two tables on `Task`. Depending on what sort of data you have in your tables and what you want out, you may wish to do a **left join** or an **inner join**.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . Here is one method:

```
select category, sum(estimated_cost) as estimated_cost, sum(actual_cost) as actual_cost
from ((select t1.category, t1.estimated_cost, 0 as actual_cost
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select t1.category, 0, t2.actual_cost
       from t2 join
            t1
            on t1.task = t2.task
      )
     ) cc
group by category;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
     (select t1.category, sum(t1.estimated_cost) estimated_cost
      from t1
      group by t1.category
     ) A
join
     (select t1.category, sum(t2.actual_cost) actual_cost
      from t2 
      join t1 on t1.task = t2.task
      group by t1.category
     ) B
on A.category = B.category
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. It is working. But in MySQL Workbench, it shows 2 rows returned, but doesn't display rows as table.

Comment: Hi, I restarted MySQL Workbench. Now it's showing table. Thanks.

Comment: Can you look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52343563/accessing-all-rows-based-on-max-of-sum-of-diff-between-start-time-and-end-time