# Accessing all rows based on Max of Sum of Diff. between Start time and End time Columns

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL, so after trying a lot, I couldn't find appropriate solution on Stackoverflow. That's why I posted my question.[May be it's a repeating question]
I have 2 tables Driver and Ride. Structure given below:

Tables:

```
Person:

id         Name              Email                 reg_number
 37        test1           test1@gmail.com          111111
 38        test2           test2@gmail.com          222222
 39        test3           test3@gmail.com          333333 
 40        test4           test4@gmail.com          444444
 41        test5           test5@gmail.com          555555
 42        test6           test6@gmail.com          666666 

Rides:

  id     Person_id       start_time            end_time             distance
  23       38        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T13:12:12      1000
  24       39        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T14:12:12      1100
  25       40        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T13:12:12      1200
  26       41        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T15:12:12      1300
  27       42        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T15:12:12       600
  28       42        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T13:12:12       700
  29       41        2018-08-08T12:12:12     2018-08-08T16:12:12       800
```

**My Query is** : Person is a driver who rides cab.

start_time is the start time of his ride. end_time is the end time of his ride. Distance is distance in KM.

I want to pass start and end time to the query.

**Result should include** TOP 5 Persons with their email,name, total minutes of Ride, maximum ride duration in minutes.

Only rides that starts and ends within the mentioned durations should be counted.

**Note:** Total minutes of all rides by a person is the criteria for TOP.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Android . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Date/time functions are notoriously dependent on the database.  You need to tag the database you are using.

I am going to assume that you are using MySQL.

You can answer the "top 5" by using just the `rides` table:

```
select r.person_id,
       sum(to_seconds(r.end_time) - to_seconds(r.start_time)) as duration_seconds
from rides r
where r.start_time >= ? and
      r.end_time <= ?
group by r.person_id
order by duration_seconds desc
limit 5;
```

This is basically what you want.  Now you just need to add in the `person` information and convert the seconds to minutes:

```
select p.*, top5.duration_seconds / 60 as duration_minutes
from (select r.person_id,
             sum(to_seconds(r.end_time) - to_seconds(r.start_time)) as duration_seconds
      from rides r
      where r.start_time >= ? and
            r.end_time <= ?
      group by r.person_id
      order by duration_seconds desc
      limit 5
     ) top5 join
     person p
     on top5.person_id = p.id;
```

Other databases have other ways of extracting the duration between two `datetime` values.

The `?` is the placeholder for the values defining the time range.

Comment: Thanks. How to include query for getting max duration of all rides of a specific person?

Comment: @Android . . . You would use `max()` instead or in addition to `sum()`.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff : Hi, I'm passing this entire query String into @Query() annotation in Spring. It is causing many invalid Token Exception.

Comment: e.g. Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 101

Comment: e.g. : antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: sum